# discord.js - leaderboard undefined user name

Tags: javascript, undefined, discord.js, quick.db

I am using quick.db for a Leaderboard command. It can show clearly the statistics ( you can see from the image that there are someone with 5 wins, etc). However, it cannot show the correct name-tag of that user. It is undefined.

```js
const resp = await db.startsWith("money", { sort: ".data" });
resp.length = 10;
let finalOutput = " ";
for (var i in resp) {
finalOutput += `**${message.guild.members.cache.get(resp[i].ID.split("_")[1]).tag}** ~-~ ${resp[i].data} wins \n`;
  }

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${finalOutput}`)
    .setColor("#ffffff")

  message.channel.send(embed);
```

The above is my code. Is the `message.guild.members.cache.get` part wrong? If yes, what shall it be? Thank you very much.

[image: Yet, this is the result. The user tags are "undefined".]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the correct code.

`message.guild.members.cache.get`

should become:

`bot.users.cache.get`